# Woocommerce (Wordpress) retrieve all categories on product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I woul really appreciate help in this.

I have Woocommerce working. In any category I have products that belongs to different categories.

For example:
Book (Books, Gifts, Gifts for men)
Knife (Knifes, Gifts, Gifts for men)

So i need list like:

- Books
- Knifes
- Gifts
- Gifts for men

One category can be up to 100 products (for now, maybe more later).

**QUESTION: How can I retreive all categories for all products listed in particular category?**

What i've tried:

1) I've used WooCommerce widget, but it doesn't give me ALL categories (skipping some child categories).

2) I've used this code:

```
<?php
        $term = get_queried_object()->term_id;
        $termid = get_term($term, 'product_cat' );
        if($termid->parent > 0)
        {
            $args = array(
                'orderby'       => 'name',
                'order'         => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty'    => false,
                'child_of'      => $termid->parent,
            );
            $siblingproducts = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args);
            foreach ($siblingproducts as $siblingproduct) {
                if ($siblingproduct->term_id == $term ) {  ?>
                    <li>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <li>
                <?php } ?>
                <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $siblingproduct ); ?>"><?php echo $siblingproduct->name; ?><?php //echo "<span class='count'>" .  $siblingproduct->count . "</span>"; ?></a></li>
            <?php }
        } else {
            $args = array(
                'orderby'       => 'name',
                'order'         => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty'    => false,
                'child_of'      => $term
            );
            $subproducts = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args);
            foreach ($subproducts as $subproduct) { ?>
                <li> <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $subproduct ); ?>"><?php echo $subproduct->name; ?><?php //echo "<span class='count'>" . $subproduct->count . "</span>"; ?></a></li>
            <?php }
        }
        ?>
```

But again it is skipping some categories.

Comment: When you say 'How can I retreive all categories for all products listed in particular category?' - Can you please explain a bit more? I don't follow: Do you mean you will have an active product list, and you want to list all other categories that share the same parent category as those products?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Yes, exactly, i want "to list all other categories that share the same parent category as those products"

I imagine it ike this:

While loop goes through products like SELECT * FROM products WHERE parentCat = $catId

We receive array of products, and anyway it has to check DB field "parentCat", so I need some function to write value of this field in array, so I can output it as a link list